# Macro to auto email individual spreadsheets as CSV from Excel with only rows including yesterdays date and data

Tags: csv, email, auto

I am attempting auto prompt a csv attachment to email data from a spreadsheet that only includes yesterdays date set out in rows. SO far I am able to send the entire spreadsheet but I need to be more Specific. Also the dates are saving as mm/dd/yyyy, I need it to remain in dd/mm/yyyy format. Columns are A to G, with 391 rows that update each day with one variable each day

```
Public Sub Email_Sheets_As_CSV()

Dim csvFile As String
Dim wsName As Variant
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

Sheets("MonitorPro").Activate

wsName = ActiveSheet.Name
csvFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wsName & ".csv"
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs csvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

'Email the .csv files

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
.to = "importer@energyaustralia.ehsdata.com"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Monthly_Daily_Checks_Data"
.Body = "This email contains 1 .csv file attachments."
.Attachments.Add csvFile
.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

'Delete the .csv files


End Sub


Public Sub Email_Sheets_As_CSV()

Dim csvFile As String
Dim wsName As Variant
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

Sheets("MonitorPro").Activate

wsName = ActiveSheet.Name
csvFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wsName & ".csv"
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs csvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

'Email the .csv files

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
.to = "importer@energyaustralia.ehsdata.com"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Monthly_Daily_Checks_Data"
.Body = "This email contains 1 .csv file attachments."
.Attachments.Add csvFile
.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

'Delete the .csv files

End Sub
```